# How to limit which objects get rendered in my index view in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to limit the posts that will render in my view based on if they match the current_user's interest_list (set of tags).

So as a preface, it's a simple blog type website on rails. I have a user model, and a post model, each of them with controllers. I have a user that has an interest_list, and posts which have a tag_list.

In my posts index.html.erb file I have

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Relevant Posts</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render partial: 'index_post', locals: {post: post} %>
<% end %>
```

I would like, the logic to be like this

```
@posts = @posts.tagged_with(@current.user.interest_list, :match_all => true)
```

Then render the form for each post that has a tag in common with the current users interest list.

Now, these tags are dynamic, a user has the ability to change their interest and same with a post, it can be edited.

Please help me, I've never used acts_as_tagable before, and so I'm trying to learn.

Thank you very much for your help in advanced.